# Is it allowed to aggregate Stack Overflow jobs on a free to use job board?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, rss

I'm working on building a aggregated public list of jobs in software development for few of my friends and anyone else who might find it useful to get job postings from one place.

Stack Overflow is one of the sources I want to include in my app. Is it allowed to do so? And if it is allowed, what are the ways? RSS? API? Do point me into some direction.